# How to make parse query synchronous swift

Tags: xcode, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, synchronous

Is there any way to make a parse query synchronous? I tried changing the query to findObjects instead of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. I can't seem to figure out the syntax of that though. Can someone help me out with this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
    var messageQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")

    messageQuery.whereKey("GUID", equalTo: GUID)



    messageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                for object in objects {

                    println("in loop of objects retrieved")
                    object.delete()

                }

            }

            messages.removeAtIndex(messageIndex)
            //objectIDArr.removeAtIndex(messageIndex)

        }else {

            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `findObjects` method, which returns an NSArray.
[See the reference on parse](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjects)

e.g.:

```
PFQuery query = PFQuery(classname: "Message")
query.whereKey("GUID", equalTo: GUID)
NSArray messages = query.findObjects()
for message in messages {
    //do whatever you want with your message object
}
```